# Spurious click on right click in Ubuntu on VMWare

Tags: ubuntu

I am running Ubuntu 10.10 on VmWare. I have a problem with the right mouse button click. When I click it where it opens a context menu, a duplicate click effects that automatically select an item in the context menu that is pointer to. Often since the second event happens all of a sudden, the first context menu option is getting clicked. What could be the problem?